# How to Remove all table rows from Sq Lite database table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to remove all rows that i entered from my SQLite database table.I will need any new example.

Comment: no, you don't need any examples, you need to learn the **basisc** of SQL

Comment: but compare sql  to sqlite, is different ..I will need any new example query to remove all rows that i entered from my SQLite database table.

Comment: no, you will not `"need any new example query"`, you have to learn it on your own, nobody will do your homework...

Comment: OK , I will do my home work!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not have TRUNCATE TABLE command in SQLite but you can use SQLite DELETE command to delete complete data from an existing table, though it is recommended to use DROP TABLE command to drop complete table and re-create it once again.

The basic syntax of DELETE command is as follows:

`sqlite> DELETE FROM table_name;`

The basic syntax of DROP TABLE is as follows:

`sqlite> DROP TABLE table_name;`

Taken from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_truncate_table.htm)

Comment: Thanks you sir this link very useful for me..

Answer (score 0):

delete from TABLE_NAME to delete all data from table

if you want to see sample then this is best link -

http://javatechig.com/android/android-sqlite-database-tutorial

Comment: Thanks you sir this link very useful for  me..

Comment: if this answer is useful for you then please accept it.thanks